# Why only one object is drawn on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I created render method after canvas image x or y is changed. But only one image is drawn after changing position, the second one isn't drawn. It also depends in what order I add that images on the screen.

**App.js**

```
my_Doge = game.addSprite("Doge", "mydoggy", 0, 700, 100, 100);
my_Cat = game.addSprite("Cat", "mycat", 0, 0, 100, 100);

function update(){
    game.setPos(my_Cat, my_Cat.xcoord+=2, my_Cat.ycoord+=2);
    game.setPos(my_Doge, my_Doge.xcoord+=2, my_Doge.ycoord-=2);
}
```

**Library.js**

```
moopleGame.prototype.setPos = function(sprite, newX, newY)
{ // Set new sprite position
    sprite.xcoord = newX;
    sprite.ycoord = newY;

for(var i = 0; i < this.addedSprites.length; i++)
{
    this.sprite_index = 0;

    if(sprite.id == this.addedSprites[i].id) // Find index of that image in array
    {
        this.sprite_index = i;
    }
}

this.render(this.sprite_index, sprite.width, sprite.height, sprite.xcoord, sprite.ycoord);
}

moopleGame.prototype.render = function(index, width, height, x, y) // Draw image to screen
{
    ctx = this.ctx;

    this.fillCanvas();

    this.addedSprites[index].x = x;
    this.addedSprites[index].y = y;

    var w = new Image();
    w.src = this.addedSprites[index].src;

    ctx.drawImage(w, this.addedSprites[index].x,
    this.addedSprites[index].y,
    this.addedSprites[index].width,
    this.addedSprites[index].height);
}
```

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFPHZ.jpg)

Comment: You haven't shown the `this.fillCanvas()` method, but I'm assuming it clears the canvas. When you call `render` twice the second call will wipe out what the first call drew.

Comment: @JJJ Hey, JJJ. Yes, it this method clear the canvas.Thank you, I understood my problem. But then how should I clear the canvas and not to wipe out first object? Btw it doesn't depend on when I clear canvas : before or after drawing. Anyway only 1 object

Comment: Instead of rendering individual sprites, you'll have to make a separate "renderAll" method that first clears the screen and then re-renders all sprites on the canvas. So first clear screen, then loop through all sprites (even those whose position has not changed) and draw them to the canvas.

Comment: @JJJ, thank you. Can you please code it? Cause I don't know how to realize it. As you can see, I call render() method after changing x and y. So what should I do? How to render not separated object, but render all objects at the same time? Thanks in advance )

Comment: @JJJ , I've found the solution: thank yo man